# Maximum path sum in a 2d matrix

Tags: c

I have to find the maximum path sum from top to bottom until I reach the 
last row of the matrix.

I have to use a recursive function that returns the maximum sum. While going down we can only move one row down and one column to the right or left or straight down. My code is only returning the first index of the matrix. Is my logic and also the parameters that I have used for my function correct?

```c
    int mat[3][3], i, j;

    printf("Enter the elements of the matrix :\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("%d", MaximumPath(mat, 0, 0));
}

int MaximumPath(int Mat[][N], int i, int j) {
    // IF we reached to first row of 
    // matrix then return value of that 
    // element  
    if (i == 0 && j = 0)
        return Mat[i][j]

    // out of matrix bound 
    if (i = N || j < 0)
        return 0;

    // call all rest position that we reached
    // from current position and find maximum 
    // between them and add current value in 
    // that path 
    return max(MaximumPath(Mat, i - 1, j), 
               MaximumPath(Mat, i - 1, j - 1), 
               MaximumPath(Mat, i - 1, j + 1)))
               + Mat[i][j];
}

int max(int i, int j, int k) {
    if ((i > j) && (i > k)) {
        return i;
    } else
    if ((j > i) && (j > k)) {
        return j;
    } else
    if ((k > i) && (k > j)) {
        return k;
    }
}
```

Comment: You said you need to use a recursive function, but you don't actually have one.

Comment: I changed my code...if u would please have a look now

Comment: @m.raynal: sorry about your edit, it looks like we had the same urge to fix the presentation :)

Comment: @FahidShadman: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- There is a syntax error in `if (i == 0 && j = 0)`: it should be `j == 0`, but there is no reason to return when you are at the top left corner, this is where you start!
- There is a missing `;` at the end of `return Mat[i][j]`
- There is an extra parenthesis at the end of `MaximumPath(Mat, i - 1, j + 1)))`
- You should pass `i + 1` to your recursive calls to `MaximumPath`, not `i - 1`.
- you should check if `j` is inside the matrix boundaries and return `0` if not, and fix the test `if (i = N || j < 0)` as

  ```
  if (i >= N || j < 0 || J >= N)
  ```
- The `max` function is incorrect too: it does not return a value if 2 values are equal and larger than the third.
- you should probably try other starting points, such as (0, 1) and (0, 2). Otherwise, it is moot the enter values for these cells as well as cell (1, 2).

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 3

int MaximumPath(int Mat[][N], int i, int j);

int main() {
    int mat[N][N], i, j;
    int max;

    printf("Enter the elements of the matrix :\n");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]) != 1)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    max = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        max = max3(max, max, MaximumPath(mat, 0, j));
    }
    printf("%d\n", max);
    return 0;
}

int max3(int i, int j, int k) {
    if (i >= j && i >= k) {
        return i;
    } else
    if (j >= i && j >= k) {
        return j;
    } else {
        return k;
    }
}

int MaximumPath(int Mat[][N], int i, int j) {
    // out of matrix boundaries
    if (i >= N || j < 0 || j >= N)
        return 0;

    // compute the maximum path from the current cell
    // for all possible directions:
    return max3(MaximumPath(Mat, i + 1, j - 1), 
                MaximumPath(Mat, i + 1, j), 
                MaximumPath(Mat, i + 1, j + 1)) + Mat[i][j];
}
```

Note that is would be more efficient to test for the boundaries before recursing:

```c
int max(int i, int j) {
    if (i >= j)
        return i;
    else
        return j;
}

int MaximumPath(int Mat[][N], int i, int j) {
    if (i >= N - 1) {
        // reached the last row
        return Mat[i][j];
    } else {
       // try all possible paths
       int v = MaximumPath(Mat, i + 1, j)
       if (j > 0)
           v = max(v, MaximumPath(Mat, i + 1, j - 1));
       if (j < N - 1)
           v = max(v, MaximumPath(Mat, i + 1, j + 1));
       return Max[i][j] + v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see several small issues in your code, even if globally the idea on how to find a maximum value path is respected and understood.
If I did get your explanations well, there are three possible moves: down, down&left, down&right.
Which gives more or less this code:

```
int MaximumPath(int Mat[][N], int i, int j){
    // reached last row -> final case
    if (i == N-1){
            return Mat[i][j];
    }
    int max_value = MaximumPath(Mat, i+1, j);
    int tmp;
    if (j > 0){
        tmp = MaximumPath(Mat, i+1, j-1);
        if (tmp > max_value){
            max_value = tmp;
        }
    }
    if (j < N-1){
        tmp = MaximumPath(Mat, i+1, j+1);
        if (tmp > max_value){
            max_value = tmp;
        }
    }
    return max_value + Mat[i][j];
}
```